# NXP Desfire EV1 versus J3D081 - JCOP Card

Tags: java, compare, smartcard

I am a total newbie in cardware and would like to know some advantage of an 
- "conventional" NXP Desfire EV1 8K to an 
- NXP J3D081 means P5CD081 JCOP 80K Chip with Desfire EV1 Emulation.

Do I really need such a Java-card for purposes of PKI, Single sign on, OTP and so on or would it be possible to realize with the "simple" EV1 also?

Or:
the JCOP-Card may be programmed by Java - but how the Desfire EV1 "without JAVA" is programmed it?

Thanks a lot for all explications what would illuminate my "confusion".

fizz

Answer (score 1):

The things you are talking about normally require asymmetric cryptography, which is not present on a Desfire  memory card. So basically you need a smart card with asymmetric co-processor.

Memory cards like the Desfire are not programmed; they are relatively simple cards that can store encrypted/authenticated data and perform symmetric authentication. You cannot write programs to run on them.

Comment: Anything missing from my answer, dear new user? If not, please accept. If so, please indicate what is missing.

Comment: Excuse me dear Maarten, are DESFire cards a kind of Native cards? or they are Java Cards? Or they are just simple memory cards? I read the wiki page about Mifare cards, but it doesn't clarify somethings  about DESFire cards. Does they support post-issuance applications? Or some specific applications masked in ROM and there is no way to add or remove any one? Any light on this issue highly appreciated.

Comment: @Abraham In short they are relatively advanced memory cards that provide symmetric authentication and encryption capabilities. They don't contain a general purpose CPU.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. But in Wiki it is mentioned that they have some applications such as _Advanced public transportation_, _Access management_, _Loyalty_ and _Micropayment_. Based on your comment, I can conclude this applications are fixed and no way to remove or add, no life-cycle, no security domain and nothing related to GlobalPlatform. right?

Comment: @Abraham Rigth, I would take that kind of information with a grain of salt. It's got authentication and secure storage. As long as you are ok with symmetric primitives for that then you can build any kind of protocol or application on top of it. Cheap chips that provide some symmetric functionality using standardized algorithms - nothing more nothing less. Definitely better than Mifare of course.